# Variable in a dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, dynamic

I have a problem once I want to run the next query:

```
declare @j int = 1;

declare @column varchar(255);
set @column = 'last_name';

declare @tmp varchar(255); 
declare @query nvarchar(255) = N'select ' + @column + N' from TEST where id = @j'

declare @tbl table(tmp varchar(255)) 

insert into @tbl 
exec sp_executesql @query

select top 1 @tmp = tmp from @tbl 

select @tmp

select * from @tbl;
```

The problem is that if I change the variable `@j` to a numeric value in the declaration of the `@query` variable, like this

```
declare @query nvarchar(255) = N'select ' + @column + N' from TEST where id = 1'
```

the query is running successfully, if I left the `@j` variable there, like this

```
declare @query nvarchar(255) = N'select ' + @column + N' from TEST where id = @j'
```

I got an error message:

"Must declare the scalar variable `@j`."

Why? And how can I solve that my query would work with the variable `@j`?

Comment: Why do you have that inconsistency in concatenation - @column is concatenated without quotes and @j is within quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the place of ==== `where id = @j'`

change like this may it works

Convert(nvarchar(2), @j);

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `@j` variable to string. AS its type is [INT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) you should cast it as

```
CAST(@j AS VARCHAR(12))
```

Also, you can pass parameters to dynamic SQL statement when it is executed using `sp_executesql`. In your case it will be something like this:

```
declare @j int = 1;

declare @column varchar(255);
set @column = 'last_name';

declare @tmp varchar(255); 
declare @query nvarchar(255) = N'select ' + @column + N' from TEST where id = @j'

declare @tbl table(tmp varchar(255)) 

insert into @tbl 
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@j INT', @j = @j

select top 1 @tmp = tmp from @tbl 

select @tmp

select * from @tbl;
```

In the following line:

exec sp_executesql @query, N'@j INT', @j = @j

1. `@query` is your dynamic T-SQL statement
2. `N'@j INT'` is declaration of parameters
3. `@j = @j` is parameters assignments

[sp_executsql documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameters in the sp_executesql statement like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable (
    TempID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    SomeDescription VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(TempID))

INSERT INTO TempTable (SomeDescription) 
VALUES ('Description 1'),
    ('Description 2'),
    ('Description 3')

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500) = 'SELECT * FROM TempTable WHERE TempID = @TempVar',
        @params NVARCHAR(500) = '@TempVar int',
        @j INT = 2;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @TempVar = @j;
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @j int = 1;

declare @column varchar(255);
set @column = 'last_name';

declare @tmp varchar(255); 
declare @query nvarchar(255) = N'select ' + @column + N' from TEST where id ='+ CAST(@j AS VARCHAR(5))

declare @tbl table(tmp varchar(255))

insert into @tbl 
exec (@query)

select top 1 @tmp = tmp from @tbl

select @tmp

select * from @tbl;

```
enter code here
```